# Parallelize DictVectorizer Creation

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn

I'd like to know if it is possible to merge multiple DictVectorizers. Here's an example:

1. I have 4 text documents.
2. Each document is sent to a separate thread that generates a dictionary of features.
3. When the threads return, the dictionaries are placed together into a list.
4. The list-of-dictionaries is sent to DictVectorizer.

The last step dominates the running time. Instead of having the threads return dictionaries, I'd like them to return their own DictVectorizers, and merge the DictVectorizers at the end. I realize that this will require changing the indices inside of the resulting DictVectorizer (since some features may be absent / present in different documents).

TL;DR - Is there any way to parallelize the creation of a DictVectorizer from a list-of-dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an efficient way to combine the output of several DictVectorizer. You can probably hack something together by making a first pass only fitting to build the dictionary, then combine the dictionaries into a big one with all your features and finally transform with the whole set passed to each DictVectorizer and finally stack the result matrices. This is unnecessarily complicated and won't guarantee you a speed increase.

Parallelization is the ideal use case for a [FeatureHasher](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html). It can also accept dictionaries over (feature_name, value). For example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction FeatureHasher
import scipy

vect = FeatureHasher(n_features=4, non_negative=True)

# thread 1 
l1 = [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}]
X1 = vect.fit_transform(l1) 
# thread 2
l2 = [{'foo': 3, 'baz': 1}]
X2 = vect.fit_transform(l2)
```

At the end combine the results:

```
>>> scipy.sparse.vstack([X1, X2]).toarray()
array([[ 1.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Just make sure that you use a large enough number of features (like 2**18) so that there are no collisions.

Comment: Thanks so much!! That worked fantastically well. Note that I didn't need the "toarray()" call. I was able to pass the scipy.sparse.vstack directly into my LinearSVC to perform the fit.

Comment: @Naijaba, glad to hear! You are right, `toarray()` was just for illustration. Bear in mind though that some algorithms don't accept sparse matrices.